# How to add sound to a button if a counter reaches a specific number?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to make sound with a button when my counter reaches a number, so that when I click the button and counter reaches specific number the sound is played.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int ScoreTeamA = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        displayForTeamA(0);
        final MediaPlayer beepsounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beepsound);
        Button playbeepsound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.three_points);

        playbeepsound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                beepsounds.start();
            }
        });

    }

    public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    public void threepoints(View v) {
        ScoreTeamA += 1;
        displayForTeamA(ScoreTeamA);

        if (ScoreTeamA == 33) {      
            ScoreTeamA = 0;
        }
    }

    public void resetscore(View v) {
        ScoreTeamA = 0;
        displayForTeamA(0);
    }
}
```

With this code I am having the sound, but counter stays at zero.

Comment: Well, right now your button just plays the sound. Instead, your `OnClickListener` should do whatever is needed to change the counter if you want that to happen on a button click - e.g. call `threepoints(v)` if that's the method you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You have done the mistake at on `OnClickListener` as it's playing only the sound. Now I have done call the method and once the count reached at **33** then the sound will play and the ScoreTeamA set to zero. I think this is what you want to implement

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int ScoreTeamA = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    displayForTeamA(0);
    final MediaPlayer beepsounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beepsound);
    Button playbeepsound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.three_points);

    playbeepsound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            threepoints(v);
        }
    });

}

public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void threepoints(View v) {
    ScoreTeamA += 1;
    displayForTeamA(ScoreTeamA);

    if (ScoreTeamA == 33) {      
        ScoreTeamA = 0;
        beepsounds.start();
    }
}

public void resetscore(View v) {
    ScoreTeamA = 0;
    displayForTeamA(0);
}
```

}

Comment: The above code would crash with a NullPointerException or similar because `beepsounds.start()` is not in scope inside the `threepoints()` method. (should be called `threePoints()` (Android/Java/Kotlin methods are expected to be `calledLikeThis()`. And that would only happen when the score reaches 33 and the code inside tries to do `start` on a nonexistent reference. In fact that code does not compile now that I think of it :)

Comment: At the very least, change this line: `final MediaPlayer beepsounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beepsound);` to `this.beepsounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beepsound);` and add to the class: `final MediaPlayer beepsounds;`. Don't forget to destroy it and release it in the `onDestroy()` method or you will leak memory in the native code of the MediaPlayer.